# How can i drag jquery dialog box outside the nyromodal iframe

Tags: jquery, html, nyromodal

I'm currently working on a task in which I have opened nyromodal iframe and inside nyromodal i have opened jquery draggable dialog box.  It works fine inside the iframe but I cannot drag jquery dialog box outside the iframe. Have anybody idea how can I do this?